# Height of div increasing when view-port extends horizontally

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

I am working on a horizontal scrolling website and ran into an odd issue. When the window is re-sized horizontally, the height of the header div changes. Any thoughts as to what may be causing this?

My basic html looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<header class="header" id="header"></header>
<div class="content" id="content"></div>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.container {
box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute;
float: left;
margin-right: -999999px;
height: 100%;
padding: 50px 0;
max-height: 600px;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

.header {
float: left;
padding: 0 50px 0 0;
height: 100%;
max-height: 500px;
position: fixed!important;
z-index: 1234;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content{
margin-left: 320px;
height: 100%;
margin-right: -999999px;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Are your header and content elements empty in the site you're working on? It could be related to the content within the elements.

Comment: "header" has a child div that with {width: 270px; height of 100%; overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: auto;} and "content" has a child div with {float: left; position: relative;height:100%}

Comment: My first thought is that you have content that is dropping onto a new line. Try adding `overflow-y:hidden;` to the header

Comment: @SamWillis Thanks for the suggestion. Gave it a try, but unfortunately it didn't work. Something else to note is that the header does not remain fixed in mobile chrome. I am not sure whether that is a separate issue or if it is also related to this somehow.

Comment: Are there any media queries that could be overwriting the fixed positioning? Do you have a live site anywhere that we could see the code on?